# Check if User input correct ipv4 format

Tags: python-3.x, netmiko

My first time here, i have a question please:

i want to check if user type on input an ipv4 if it's not ipv4 user should receive error 3 times and then exit. My example code below:

```
    # Hosts and Commands
    for attempt in range(3):
        host = input("Enter IPs separated by SPACE: ")
        cmd = input("Enter Command(s) seperated by ',' : ")
        if(len(host) != 0) and (len(cmd) != 0):
            break
        print("Fields Cannot be Blank, try again...")
    else:
        Screen().input("Sorry...Execution Terminated, Press [ENTER] to Exit")
        return
```

Comment: An IPv4 address is four numbers separated by three dots. Each number must be integers in the range `0` to `255` (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

```
def validateIP(s):
    if not s: return False
    try:
        parts = [int(p) for p in s.split('.')]
    except:
        return False

    if len(parts) != 4: return False
    for part in parts:
        if not(0 <= part <= 255):
            return False
    return True


max_attempts = 3
for remaining in range(max_attempts-1, -1, -1):
    ip = input("Enter an IPv4 address: ")
    if validateIP(ip.strip()): break
    print("That is an invalid IPv4 address. You have", remaining, "attempts left")
```

Comment: Perhaps add a `if len(parts) != 4` check as well?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you inspectorG4dget! It worked fine if i add only one IP in the array, if i type more than 1 separated by space to be captured later in an array it doesn't work. The idea is to receive as many ip as user desire to consult but the user cannot type non valid ipv4.